# Determining whether the current time is before 5pm that day

Tags: php, date, time

I want to have code in a loop that only runs if it is before 5pm on any day.

What code would do this?

```
IF (current_time < 5:00pm) {
   // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple one that gets the job done:

```
if (date('H') < 17)
{
    // DO SOMETHING
}
```

Just remember that this date comes from the server. So, if the client is in another timezone, that may not work as required. The good thing about this, is that the user can't change his computer date in order to trick the site into something.

And if you want to do that with javascript (where the value will come from the user's computer), just do the following:

```
var today = new Date();
if (today.getHours() < 17)
{
    // DO SOMETHING
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This solution uses the nice PHP5 `DateTime` class, and avoids the clunky old `strtotime()` function:

```
$hoursNow = new DateTime()->format('H');
if($hoursNow < 17) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: Does this take DST into account?

Comment: @Jamie, yes if server's timezone uses DST (or timezone set)

Comment: can you please briefly explain why this is better than just `date('H')`?

Comment: @jlcd - it's not better; it's basically the same thing, only using the newer OOP api. What it does bring is a bit more flexibility; you can do a lot more with the DateTime object than you can with the old date/time functions. You may not need it for the specific example given, but given the question, there's a good chance he'd find some of that functionality useful elsewhere in the same program.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(time() < strtotime('today 05:00 pm')) {
   // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: +1 because it will work, but I try to avoid `strtotime()` wherever possible these days - it's not necessary any more in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

In short...

```
$t = time(); # or any other timestamp
if (date('H', $t) < 17) {
  // Do stuff
  }
```

Works for any day

Note: Make sure your timezone is correct (check php config or just use [date_default_timezone_se](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)t function before calling [date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function)